# has the linux kernel support sctp protocol in container of LXC/docker yet?

Tags: linux-kernel, docker, lxc, sctp

I'm using docker to set up an application in container which will use sctp for communication. The network connection is fine, i can ping each other, but I run the sctp-test from lksctp_tools and met problem below:

```
[root@a2c771287273]#sctp_test -H 0 -P 250 -l                                                                                                      
local:addr=0.0.0.0, port=250, family=2
seed = 1417166664

Starting tests...
socket(SOCK_SEQPACKET, IPPROTO_SCTP)

*** socket: failed to create socket:  Address family not supported by protocol ***
```

i did a little google and found out reason from post in lxc mailing list that it's because the kernel doesn't support sctp protocol in linux container. for details, please refer to post below:

https://www.mail-archive.com/lxc-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03826.html

But it was two years ago, I'm wondering if it's supported by kernel now. the version of kernel i'm using is 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64, do i need to use other kernel? or anyone of you met same problem as me and happen to have some workaround here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally, Docker requires a version of the kernel newer than 3.8 - see [docs](https://docs.docker.com/installation/binaries/#check-kernel-dependencies).  RedHat have back-ported many of the fixes, however.

Comment: it does work now when I switch to newer kernel, thanks, Bryan.